# What should i do if logistic regression model has high bias (training error)?

Tags: machine-learning

I have built the logistic regression model, but the bias seems to be high (training error).

What should I do to reduce the bias?

Comment: Do you know about cross validation?

Comment: Yes. I believe cross validation is to avoid overfitting. It is for high variance models. What to do with High bias (under-fitting models) ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should know the extent of bias by plotting it.
   [This link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html) may help
2. You need to increase model complexity by adding more features that help your model to identify sample class.

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by plotting a 'learning curve'. This curve shows if your model is improving as you keep adding more and more data. This will help you understand if you need more data.

Then, the usual stuff you can try in a high bias case are:

- Add more features and/or polynomial terms
- Decrease the regularization (if you are using any)